# Placing elements below other elements in Framelayout with Linearlayout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I created a android layout xml for some of my screens, and apparently I am using a navigation drawer in my app which is why I am using a frame layout. Now I've added a linear layout that will show the following:

A text view with a submit button

2 image buttons

This is a sample layout of what I want:

[image]

The problem is when I made my layout, I can't seem to pull down the 2 buttons to make them below the submit and because what happens is that both of the buttons are on the right side  of the layout, like this:

[image]

This is my xml code:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="mypackage.test.HomeActivity" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <LinearLayout 
            android:id="@+id/linerlayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
              android:gravity="center_horizontal"

            >
                    <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Enter ID"
            >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Submit" /> 
         <!--
        I'm trying to put the two buttons here but what happens is they both disappear when I put them

        -->      

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:text="Button"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:text="Button" 
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>          
        </LinearLayout>

        </FrameLayout>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
        android:name="mypackage.test.NavigationDrawerFragment"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

How do I pull the two buttons to go down? Should I transfer the buttons to another layout?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can put the two other buttons outside of the LinearLayout layout so that they
will appear on the bottom. Like this:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linerlayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"

        >
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Enter ID"
            >
        <requestFocus />
        </EditText>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Submit" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: I tried placing them outside, but it is causing all of the other elements to go out of place inside the framelayout.

Comment: please use the code I posted as I tried it in my Android Studio and seems to be okay.

Comment: I see. I tried moving mine without checking the entire code. Will test it now.

Comment: Tested it and now it works.  I see that you just need to add gravity for the buttons to make them go where you want them. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="mypackage.test.HomeActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button1"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="Enter ID">

                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:text="Submit" />


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button3"
                android:text="Button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText1" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:text="Button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/button3"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button3" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </FrameLayout>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```